See me Once, See me Twice #16
It has been 4 years since my last riddle. Here we go!

See me once, let's call my gay friend, and tell him I'm here.
See me twice, A loud agreement, just to be clear.

I will try to give hints daily if needed.
If you are not familiar with my See me once riddles, I recommend you first have a look at the latest riddles in this series and their solutions:
#10, #11, #12, #13, #14, #15

I think the answer is

 Hear

See me once, let's call my gay friend, and tell him I'm here.

 Hear is a homophone (call my gay friend) for here.

See me twice, A loud agreement, just to be clear.

 Hear, hear is a phrase often used to express loud and clear agreement.


Can you hear it too? I think it is the sound of a winner. Well done! I thought maybe the userbase from 4+ years ago would have rotated, but here you still are, looking through my riddles as if they were glass. :)
